# mp3 playlist without flash and working with all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, mp3, playlist

I'm creating a Songs site, there are playlists and mp3 files.
I founded alot of flash mp3 playlist players, but I wish to do it without flash, and to work with all browsers and smart phones like iphone , android ...etc.
can you please help me.
best regards.
zuhair

Comment: That's not possible, because older browser do not understand the `<audio>`-Tag. See this: http://caniuse.com/audio

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

http://webplayer.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to use something that tries html5's audio tag first but falls back to flash or vice versa. One thing to note is that android completely fails when it comes to its implementation of html5 audio. Especially with playlists. The best solution I found was to simply give a link to an mp3. Android will start playing it with the default native audio player.

Also note that one disadvantage is that not every browser plays mp3's. You will have to encode in ogg to reach the widest browser support possible. If you have a library of audio this can easily become a big issue.

You could make player/playlist yourself. However if your relatively new to this sort of thing you will be pulling your hair out in no time. Try something like [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org). jPlayer has a playlist add on. You can theme it yourself if you want a different look.